# SonarQube: Source is not present in module base directory

Tags: sonarqube

We have been executing sonar analysis successfully with SQ-4.5.4 version with no issues. Suddenly since couple days our sonar analysis build is failing with below error message:

It is not indexing any source file even though it has found them. We have made no changes in our pom.xml or project structure. I am not sure why it is adding "build/sonar" to base directory path that I have mentioned in pom.xml for project base directory. I tried giving relative path too but still issue is reproducible.

```
[INFO] [14:03:23.298] Base dir: /opt/customer/ci_workspace/sonar/10.1.0/TN/build/sonar
[INFO] [14:03:23.302] Source encoding: ISO-8859-1, default locale: en_US
[INFO] [14:03:23.304] Index files
[WARN] [14:03:24.008] File '/opt/customer/ci_workspace/sonar/10.1.0/TN/access/Application/src/com/panther/ph/access/persistence/cocobase/AccessBP.java' is ignored. It is not located in module basedir '/opt/customer/ci_workspace/sonar/10.1.0/TN/build/sonar'.
```

I have mentioned below property in my pom.xml

"/opt/customer/ci_workspace/sonar/10.1.0/TN
../../access/Application/src"

Answer (score 0):

The base directory is where your POM is located and your analysis launched.

The problem is that in the POM, you are referring to a source folder that is not located in a sub-folder of the base directory. This is not supported in SonarQube - and this is actually not a standard structure for source code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. But I do have a question on this. Since when sonarqube has stopped supporting this becuase our sonar build has been going smooth for a very long time. Our current version is 4.5.4 and we have been using this for a month or so . Prior to that we were using 3.2.1.

Comment: according to analysis parameter document of sonarqube, it says "Use this property when you need analysis to take place in a directory other than the one from which it starts. E.G. analysis begins from jenkins/jobs/myjob/workspace but the files to be analyzed are in ftpdrop/cobol/project1. The path may be relative or absolute.
Specify not the the source directory, but some parent of the source directory. The value specified here becomes the new "analysis directory", and other paths are then specified as though the analysis were starting from the new sonar.projectBaseDir."

Answer (score 0):

@Fabrice: The issue was someone had made some changes in repository which made our sonar-maven-plugin degrade to 2.0 version from 2.6 due to which it has failed.

@Everyone: If you are facing similar issue please check your sonar-maven-plugin is at least 2.6 version.