# Analysing a React Native Project Using SonarQube?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, sonarqube

[image]

I have installed sonarqube inside a virtual machine in my system.And is able to access it from anywhere inside my local network.

I am trying to analyse the java-script files of my react-native project which is inside the app folder as shown in the above screenshot.

so i set up a sonar-project.properties file inside the base directory of react-native project(as shown in the above screenshot) according to the sonarqube official doc in the below link

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner

and from the base directory i am trying push the file using sonar-scanner command (i am doing this from outside the virtual machine from my system os).

and it shows sonar-scanner command not found(as in the blow screenshot).
[image]

How does this   sonar-scanner command work ?,when accessing sonarserver from outside the virtualmachine do need something extra in my system os other than sonar-project.properties file in my projects root directory ? ,do i need to install something in my system os  to use the command sonar-scanner.

And what does the below property do

// To import the LCOV report

```
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath=report/lcov.dat
```

And how do i properly configure it for my project ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31945819/sonarqube-source-is-not-present-in-module-base-directory) SO question.

Comment: @JeroenHeier i have updated the question, it not just a matter of directories

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described on https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner, you have to follow these steps:

1. Download the executable for your platform
2. Extract it somewhere
3. Add the `sonar-scanner` executable (that was expanded in `<install_directory>/bin` folder

Alternatively, because you are developing a JS project, you can also use the [SonarQube Scanner for JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sonarqube-scanner) thanks to which you won't have to bother with the standard SonarQube Scanner and its properties file. For example, you can write the following script and add it to your `package.json` file:

```
let sonarqubeScanner = require('sonarqube-scanner');

sonarqubeScanner({
  serverUrl : "https://localhost:9000",
  token : "019d1e2e04eefdcd0caee1468f39a45e69d33d3f",
  options : {}
}, callback);
```

Comment: Amal P: just for the record, which solution did you chose? Running `sonar-scanner` or using the JS `sonarqube-scanner` package?

Comment: The first one - Running sonar-scanner